# resize viewportHeight and viewportWidth of XML Vector image

Tags: android-studio, vector-icons

At first, I'm sorry for my bad English .

In my android project, I used icons in the vector XML file. there, some icons viewportHeight and viewportWidth size so large, and these icons get problems in small display size devices ( height <= 720px ). The Icons that are large size viewportHeight and viewportWidth, I created that in SVG using AI.

My question is, is there any way to reduce the XML vector viewportHeight and viewportWidth size?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change mine and I realized that when you increase viewpoint measurements the SVG becomes smaller and vice-versa

Comment: Yes, it's maybe not possible from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem.

1. I open my vector SVG file from Adobe Illustrator.
2. Select the whole equipment of my SVG file using dragging and select (or ctrl+A).
3. Go to the properties of this image.

And here I find the weight(W) and height (H) of my vector image.
This value is equal to the viewport value of the android studio .xml file. I reduced this value and fixed the problem.

[image: Properties of Vector image in AI]